# Are AFNetworking success/failure blocks invoked on the main thread?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Does AFNetworking call the completion block on the main thread? or is it called in the background, requiring me to manually dispatch my UI updates to the main thread?

Using code instead of words, this is the example code from the [AFNetworking documentation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) with the call to `NSLog` replaced by a UI update:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    self.label.text = JSON[@"text"];
} failure:nil];
```

Should it be written like this instead?

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.label.text = JSON[@"text"];
    });
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: @tdarr all the source code are available, take a look and you can know it all

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In AFNetworking 2, [`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/3e12404b2d1693f7bdea3ff435f2e419d5c7a531/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h#L160-L167) has a `completionQueue` property.

> The dispatch queue for the `completionBlock` of request operations.
>            If `NULL` (default), the main queue is used.

```
    #if OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC
    @property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
    #else
    @property (nonatomic, assign, nullable) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
    #endif
```

In AFNetworking 3, the `completionQueue` property has been moved to [`AFURLSessionManager`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/326ccb170d2ea2202e324e562196a82e8618f94a/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h#L156-L159) (which `AFHTTPSessionManager` extends).

> The dispatch queue for `completionBlock`. If `NULL` (default), the
>   main queue is used.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
```

Comment: I agree! I edited the answer to include AFNetworking 3 and to add links to the source of both versions.

Comment: @thomasd thanks. There are some rejections on your edit, so I can't accept it, but I just copied it again.

Answer (score 43):

They are invoked on the main queue, unless you explictly sets the queue on `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, as shown in `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure` from `AFHTTPRequestOperation.m`

```
self.completionBlock = ^{
    if (self.error) {
        if (failure) {
            dispatch_async(self.failureCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                failure(self, self.error);
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (success) {
            dispatch_async(self.successCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                success(self, self.responseData);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Good to know probably should have checked and not assumed they just executed them on the same thread as the request

Answer (score 6):

As everyone explained, it's in the source code of the AFNetworking, as for the way to do it,

**AFNetworking 2.xx:**

```
// Create dispatch_queue_t with your name and DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL as for the flag
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.CompanyName.AppName.methodTest", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

// init AFHTTPRequestOperation of AFNetworking
operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Set the FMDB property to run off the main thread
[operation setCompletionQueue:myQueue];
```

**[AFNetworking 3.xx](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Classes/AFURLSessionManager.html#//api/name/completionQueue):**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
[self setCompletionQueue:myQueue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the completion callback queue by specifying completionGroup, completionQueue [see the AFNetworking API document](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0-RC2/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html)