# can't set UIButton title in UITableViewCell with block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, block

I have a `UIButton` in a custom `UITableViewCell`, when I press the button it will post data to my server using `AFNetworking`，in the success block I set a new button title, but it doesn't work.
In `CutomTableViewCell` I use a protocol so I can respond button click:

```
@implementation SubjectReplyCell

- (IBAction)btnReplyPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(postData:atIndex:)]) {
        [self.delegate postData:self atIndex:sender.tag];
    }
}
@end
```

Then I implementation the delegate and post data to server:

```
@implementation BBSDetailsController
- (void)postData:(SubjectReplyCell *)cell atIndex:(NSInteger)idx {
    urlString = [API_HOST stringByAppendingString:BBS_PRAISE_OPPOSITION];
    __weak typeof(SubjectReplyCell) *weakCell = cell;

    [requestManager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject[@"returnode"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
            //it doesn't work
            [weakCell.btnReply setTitle:@"newTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

But if I set title out of the block it work well:

```
- (void)postData:(SubjectReplyCell *)cell atIndex:(NSInteger)idx {
    urlString = [API_HOST stringByAppendingString:BBS_PRAISE_OPPOSITION];

    //it work
    [cell.btnReply setTitle:@"newTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [requestManager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject[@"returnode"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {

        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking uses the main queue by default for failure and completion blocks, so you don't need to worry about invoking the main thread for UI changes yourself. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225193/are-afnetworking-success-failure-blocks-invoked-on-the-main-thread)

You need to use the `__block` keyword (that's two underscores) if you want to modify an object inside a block. Using `__block` tells the compiler ahead of time that you plan on mutating the object inside a block, so treat this object differently in order to keep the changes.

So this:

```
__weak typeof(SubjectReplyCell) *weakCell = cell;
```

should be this:

```
__block typeof(SubjectReplyCell) *weakCell = cell;
```

edit:
You shouldn't need to use `__weak` on your cell because modifying your cell in this block should not create a reference loop. In this case your cell will be retained in the completion block, but the cell does not also retain the block itself, so these two will not create a retain cycle.

You need to use `__weak` if the two objects in play have a chance of causing a retain cycle, like when you capture self in a block and that block is also captured by self. [Here's another answer for some more clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030873/always-pass-weak-reference-of-self-into-block-in-arc)